# Calculating distance from centroid to another point in Python

Tags: python

I have a data frame like below

```
STORE_ID LATITUDE LONGITUDE GROUP
1        18.2738  28.38833  2
2        18.3849  28.29374  1
3        18.3948  28.29303  1
4        18.1949  28.28248  1        
5        18.2947  28.47392  1
6        18.7493  28.29475  2
7        18.4729  28.38392  3
8        18.1927  28.29485  2
9        18.2948  28.29384  1
10       18.1038  28.29489  3
11       18.7482  28.29374  1
12       18.9283  28.28484  2
```

And a second data frame like below

```
Tele_Booth_ID LATITUDE LONGITUDE
1             18.5638  28.19374  
2             18.2947  28.03727 
3             18.3849  28.26395 
4             18.9482  28.91847
```

The first data frame has longitudes and latitudes of stores in a certain area. The store are grouped together into clusters represented by the GROUP field.

The second dataframe has longitudes and latitudes for telephone booths in that same area.

Using both these data frames I want to find the optimal locations to place more telephone booths.

If a store group has no telephone booths in the cluster or near the cluster, I would want to put a booth there. If a store group has a booth within the cluster, I would not want another booth there.

Using python how can I calculate the center point for each store group and then calculate the distance of each store group to the nearest booth?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am unsure of how accurate the computation of the centroid of point might be, using the ability to group on store groups You can create a new dataframe which contains the mean of the Lat and Lon of each group as follows:

Given a df1 as shown:

```
    Store   Lat Lon Group
0   1   18.2738 28.38833    2
1   3   18.3948 28.29303    1
2   4   18.1949 28.28248    1
3   5   18.2947 28.47392    1
4   6   18.7493 28.29475    2
5   7   18.4729 28.38392    3
6   8   18.1927 28.29485    2
7   9   18.2948 28.29384    1
8   10  18.1038 28.29489    3
9   11  18.7482 28.29374    1
10  12  18.9283 28.28484    2
```

Create a Dataframe of centered Lat and Lon as follows:

```
dfc = df1.groupby('Group').Lat.mean().to_frame().join(df1.groupby('Group').Lon.mean().to_frame())
```

This will yield the dfc dataframe shown below:

```
         Lat    Lon
Group       
1   18.385480   28.327402
2   18.536025   28.315693
3   18.288350   28.339405
```

You can now utilize these mean Lat/Lon points to compute distance to Telephone booths as follows:

The booth dataframe is df2 shown below:

```
    Booth   Lat Lon
0   1   18.5638 28.19374
1   2   18.2947 28.03727
2   3   18.3849 28.26395
3   4   18.9482 28.91847  

# to compute the distance between two sets of coordinates
def dist(loc1: tuple[float], loc2: tuple[float]) -> float:
    dx = loc1[0] - loc2[0]
    dy = loc1[1] - loc2[1]
    return (dx**2 + dy**2)**0.5
```

Using the above compute distance from each group centroid to each booth as follows:

```
for i in range(df2.shape[0]):
    dfc[f'B-{i+1:02}'] = dfc.apply(lambda row: dist((row.Lat, row.Lon), tuple(df2.iloc[i].to_list()[1:])), axis=1)
```

This yields the following:

```
       Lat       Lon        B-01        B-02        B-03           B-04
Group                       
1   18.385480   28.327402   0.222853    0.304003    0.063455    0.816098
2   18.536025   28.315693   0.125075    0.368452    0.159737    0.730225
3   18.288350   28.339405   0.311594    0.302202    0.122537    0.877906
```